# Capitalize ALL words in a triple String

Tags: java, string, capitalize

My program has 3 Strings, that the user has already input, the purpose for this program is to capitalize all letters in the words. How do I capitalize all letters in each word using the toUpperCase(). This is what I have so far, this is a java code

```
public static String reverseOrder(String word1, String word2, String word3) {

if (word1.length() == 0) return word1;
    return word1.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word1.substring(1).toUpperCase();
}
```

I have only done it for 1 word but I need to capitalize all 3 words, thanks
***ok new code is this

```
public static String reverseOrder(String word1, String word2, String word3) {
  int a = word1.length();
  int b = word2.length();
  int c = word3.length();

  String x;
  String y;
  String z;


  x = word1.toUpperCase();
  y = word2.toUpperCase();
  z = word3.toUpperCase();
}
}
```

Comment: You should let us know which language you're using...

Comment: [`return word3.toUpperCase() + word2.toUpperCase() + word1.toUpperCase();`](http://ideone.com/1fYcVC)?

Comment: Can you show a sample input/output?

Comment: You have a function that receives three strings and returns only one. So either you need to combine the strings together, or you need to return some sort of array/collection/object to return each of them. Also you have a lot more code than you actually need to just uppercase a string...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be over complicating a problem that can be tackled in quite a simple manner. We can convert a string to upper case as follows:

```
String exampleString = "test";
return exampleString.toUpperCase();
```

In your situation, you have three strings. Why not concatenate them all together so you can convert them as one? For example:

```
String a = "one";
String b = "two";
String c = "three";

String combined = a + b + c;
return combined.toUpperCase();
```

If you're able to modify the return type there are other options, but that may fall outside the scope of the question.